# encoding/decoding unicode and utf-8 : Python

Tags: python, unicode

I have a html text : `If I&#039;m reading lots of articles`

I am trying to replace `&#039;` and other such special characters into unicode `'`. I did

```
rawtxt.encode('utf-8').encode('ascii','ignore')
```

, but it fails

> Error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2

Comment: It looks like this is not really the code that produces the error because the error comes from trying to decode the string as ascii. Where does rawtxt come from?

Comment: @Sarien: it is the code that produces the error. You can get a decode error in a call to `encode`. See: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/conversation/python2-decode-error-when-encoding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're having problems with HTML entities, not unicode or UTF-8. Try this:

```
import HTMLParser
h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
s = h.unescape('If I&#039;m reading lots of articles')
print s
```

This prints `If I'm reading lots of articles`.

Comment: thanks for saving loads of time